# How to sort a alphanumeric list based on numbers

Tags: python

I have a list similar to this:

```
list1=['150 abc','532 rad','45 qwert']
```

I need to sort it in ascending order of numbers. However, if I use list1.sort() I get an incorrect output which is:

```
['150 abc', '45 qwert', '532 rad']
```

Comment: will the numbers will always be at start ?

Comment: yes  it will always do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to achieve what you want to .

```
l = ['150 abc','532 rad','45 qwert']
sorted_l = l.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split()[0]))
```

Here we are using `key` parameter to tell the `sort` method what should be used for sorting the list . For each item of the list , this code is first extracting the first word of the item , which is guaranteed to be a number and then it's casting it to an integer(so that sort works as we intend it to)

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution from the following [website](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/52656497.html#:%7E:text=How%20to%20sort%20alphanumeric%20list,1%27%2C%20%2710%27.):

```
sorted(list1, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
```

Out:

```
['45 qwert', '150 abc', '532 rad']
```